# How to shuffle 2 dimensional array at first level only in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have 2 dimensional array`Array<Array<Int>>` that i want to shuffle only at the first level but i haven't been successful.

```
contentTitle = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_1, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_2, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_3, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_4, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_5, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_6, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_7, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_8, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_9, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_10, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_11, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_12, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_13, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_14, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_15, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_16, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_17, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_18, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_19, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_20, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_21, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_22, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_23, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_24, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_25, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_26, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_27, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_28, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_29, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_30, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_31, R.raw.ahem_x)
            )
            contentTitle.shuffle()
```

I googled for this matter and only found shuffling for Mutable List. 
How do i achieve simple shuffle for my first level array?

Comment: Shuffle extension is not available for arrays. maybe you should convert it to a list and then shuffle it then convert it to array.
contentTitle.asList().shuffled().toTypedArray()

Comment: @RaminBoodaghi I'm very new to this. Can you show me in context to my current array?

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59907306/3144323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `array` to a `MutableList` and then shuffle the list.

In your case instead of directly creating a 2D array, try to create a `MutableList` that holds all your `Int` array's

```
var mutableList = mutableListOf(
            arrayOf(1,2,3,4),
            arrayOf(5,6,7,8),
            arrayOf(9,10,11,12),
            arrayOf(13,14,15,16))
```

Once you have a `MutableList` then you can use the `shuffle` function as

```
mutableList.shuffle()
```

After shuffling convert the `MutableList` to 2d array using

```
 var arr = mutableList.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: This is a great solution, unless performance is an issue.  If you're using arrays instead of lists, this is a major performance hit

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no `shuffle()` implementation for arrays at the moment. See [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/adding-shuffle-to-array-t-and-bytearray-intarray-et-al/8687) here and the relevant [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25651?_ga=2.108248770.1535345451.1579868553-1797340854.1559721018). Currently you can add you own implementation like:

```
fun Array.shuffle(rnd: java.util.Random) {
    // Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
    for (i in this.size - 1 downTo 1) {
        val j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1)
        val temp = this[i]
        this[i] = this[j]
        this[j] = temp
    }
}
```

The implementation based on `MutableList.shuffle()` implementation, you can find it [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollections.kt).

Another solution might be to convert the array to a list, shuffle it and convert back, but it's inefficient approach:

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val shuffledArray = array
    .toMutableList()
    .apply { shuffle() }
    .toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle extension is not available for arrays. maybe you should convert it to a list and then shuffle it then convert it to array

```
contentTitle = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_1, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_2, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_3, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_4, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_5, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_6, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_7, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_8, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_9, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_10, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_11, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_12, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_13, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_14, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_15, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_16, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_17, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_18, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_19, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_20, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_21, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_22, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_23, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_24, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_25, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_26, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_27, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_28, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_29, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_30, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_31, R.raw.ahem_x)
            ).asList().shuffled().toTypedArray()
```